# How do you summon a different companion than the one that is on a mission?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I know you can summon a companion via the icon in the bottom left of the UI via the companion (person) icon with the right arrow. Or, you can open the Crew Management window and click the same icon next to the companion you want.

If you send the companion that is currently summoned on a mission, they leave you and the bottom left portrait disappears with a countdown of the mission time replacing it. That's all cool.

But how do you summon one of your other companions that are *not* on a mission?

The summon icons are grayed out for all companions in this case whether they are on missions or not. Clicking on the portrait summon icon does nothing and provides no error message.

If you switch companions first, then send the first on a mission, you can switch between available companions no problem. It is only when you send a companion who is currently summoned that this is a problem.

Is this a bug or by design? Is their a workaround, or do you have to cancel or wait on the mission to complete before you can have any companion fight/participate in conversations with you?

[image: Crew Management window]

Comment: There is one situation where this makes some sense to me: when you send a companion to sell trash. If you could summon some other companion, tell him to sell trash and them immediatelly summon the one you had before, it would defeat the purpose of the one-minute wait.

Comment: This has been fixed :), voted to close as Too Localized.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a bug that has since been fixed.

Comment: @Mufasa I don't think this question should be closed. If the question topic is currently obsolete or not relevant, then that should be indicated in an answer. See [What should be done with out of version questions?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5727/4797) and [What do we do with historic questions that no longer make sense?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7235/4797)

Comment: @galacticninja I disagree, since online services that require running on the latest version (SWTOR is an online-only MMORPG that requires running through their servers) at all times means no one will ever see this old, bugged behavior anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the only way to summon a non-tasked companion is to close SWTOR and then log back in with your character. I have raised a support ticket about this fault, thanks for raising it up :)

Comment: Confirmed — this workaround does work. (Relogging was enough — didn't have to exit SWTOR completely.) So it looks like it's a bug. I submit a /bug ticket to them to about it.

Comment: @Mufasa: Should it be "submit" or "submitted"? I couldn't figure it out. WTB SE grammar checker.